# Display plain text as a multicolumn list using Maui c#

Tags: .net, xaml, listview, collectionview, maui

The maui ListView displays a vertical list (one column). A simplified CollectionView example sort of works, but it displays a small square on top of the each item and wastes a lot of display space between items. There has to be a way to format how items are displayed, but I have not been able to find an example.

Here is current xaml:

```
<CollectionView BackgroundColor="MistyRose"
    x:Name="collectionView"
    VerticalOptions = "Start"
    ItemSizingStrategy = "MeasureFirstItem"
    SelectionMode = "Multiple">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             Span="8"
             VerticalItemSpacing="0"
             HorizontalItemSpacing="0" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>
```

[Here is part of the current collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoRh4.gif)

[This is what I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKLRQ.gif)

Comment: use a grid with multiple columns in your data templates

Comment: OR **add to question** the code of the CollectionView example that sort of works, with an image of what it looks like now, and another image that mocks up how you want it to look.